# math. equation of a simple iterative fibonacci algorithm

Tags: iteration, fibonacci, equation

i need to find an exponential iretative mathematical equation, (starting with f(n)?), which can display the fibonacci sequence except the Binet's Formula.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried so far? Also see [mcve] and [homework](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Answer (score 0):

If you want formula for F(n) here is matrix formula

[image]

If you want to find F(n+1) from F(n) then you can use `F(n+1) = round( F(n) Phi )`, where Phi is golden section number.

Also, probably you might want to look at [Exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

Comment: are there any other options except the matrix version and the golden section? my tutor doesnt accept this both ways

Comment: @slightly1 did he told you why? Which type of formula does he want?

Comment: Im in Training currently and he said the task was to find an efficient algorithm

Comment: @slightly1, do you need to compute certain Fibonacci number or whole sequence? Hardly he expect you to find something new. May he wants you to use [Exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)

Comment: the squaring helped me, thanks! but in the end he only wanted me to write a java code of the algorithm with for-loops

Comment: @slightly1 glad to here you found some help here, now you might want to upvote or/and accept the answer ;)